# Spoiled git project at master's branch

Tags: git, github

I'm very new to git. My issue is that I have project on github, near my repo folder I created a `.rar` archive, and then by mistake made commit and then push to `master branch`. And now my github project looks like:[image]

And I can't access my VRP folder on github. It must look like:
[image]
Sorry for so stupid question, but i'm very new to git, and don't want to create new git for my project. How to fix it?
**UPDATED**:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to reset to a previous sane version of your project and force push it on Github. The process explained:

Locally, find the hash of the commit you would like to revert to. There are a number of options for you, some of them are:

```
git log
```

or

```
gitk --all
```

or

```
git reflog
```

let's say you'd like to restore hash `12345`, then:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard 12345
git push origin master -f
```

Comment: didn't helped ;( (Total 0)

Comment: can you be more specific? Total 0 what?

Comment: that log message is normal, it means there were no new objects to transfer - that's expected since all the data needed to define that tree already exists on the remote, you're just moving a branch to a previous revision. If `f3adccb` is the correct commit then you are done

Comment: I visited your repo and seems like it's what you wanted: https://github.com/litwisha/finalize

Comment: it's not that repo. it must be: github.com/litwisha/VRP . I don't quite understand why it use finalize repo, not VRP. in e\VRP folder must be VRP repo... that's interesting

Comment: well your remote currently points to https://github.com/litwisha/finalize.git. If you want to push to https://github.com/litwisha/VRP.git you'll have to define it as remote. `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/litwisha/VRP.git`

Comment: A more general comment is that you have to define what you'd like your repository structure to be. Why do you have 2 repositories? If that's intentional, do you intend to have one as a submodule of another? Seeing you're new at git I suggest you keep it simple.

Comment: can I replace whole project?

Comment: Do you mean delete a project? Now that both your repositories are in the same state you can delete one of them in GitHub. I would also reclone a new copy of the remaining project in a fresh directory on your drive to make sure you're not in some nested projects

Comment: Sometimes, when I push project, not all my files are changed in repo. So what if I want all changes to be in my repo? git push origin master -f will replace fully replace my project?

Comment: New files are untracked until you explicitly stage them (`git add`) and commit. Use `git status` to see such things. Please open new questions because we are diverging from the initial post. Have fun with Git.

Answer (score 0):

You can undo a commit. [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commit) has a guide on how to undo a commit. Basically you need to `git reset HEAD~1` but for more details go to the link or Google `git reset`